ESPNCRICINFO API call
I had been scraping ESPN data using their publicly avaialable API on the
https://hs-consumer-api.espncricinfo.com/ end points. Below is an example of one of the endpoints
v1/pages/match/scorecard?lang=en&seriesId=&matchId=
These API's were being called on espncricinfo pages through AJAX/XHR requests
Recently they introduced a change in their pages where it seems javascript is being used to add additional header that act as authentication token
x-hsci-auth-token:
exp=1727527924~hmac=9080f72a36f2b97ec94069dca3382981b2312fb10ec800ab75959a6777f344f2
Which has rendered the API inaccessible directly. I have tried to use seleniumwire to analyze requests using chrome driver and concluded that if I am able to extract the headers and invoke the API then it works.
The issue that I am facing is that when I access the required URL through selenium-wire these API calls don't happen. I can see all other calls to Adv sites and other tracking apis but consumer API calls don't happen.
Here is the code that I am using
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import requests
import time

# Set the path to your manually installed ChromeDriver
chromedriver_path = 'chromedriver.exe'

# Set up Chrome WebDriver with Selenium Wire
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Optional: to run browser in headless mode
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')  # Ignore certificate errors
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-proxy-certificate-handler')

# Selenium Wire options to disable SSL verification
seleniumwire_options = {
    'verify_ssl': False  # Disable SSL verification
}

# Manually specify the ChromeDriver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(chromedriver_path), options=chrome_options, seleniumwire_options=seleniumwire_options)

# Navigate to the target URL
driver.get('https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/germany-women-s-t20i-tri-series-2024-1444526/germany-women-vs-italy-women-final-1444537/full-scorecard')

# Capture the cookies and convert them to a format usable by the requests library
time.sleep(5)
req_headers = {}
req_url = ''
# Capture and filter the XHR requests after the div is loaded
for request in driver.requests:
    
    if 'scorecard' in request.url and 'xhr' in request.headers.get('X-Requested-With', '').lower() and request.response.status_code == 200:
        req_url = request.url
        # print(request.response.headers)
        req_headers = request.headers

        print("Found headers for the needed URL")
        break

# Close the WebDriver session
driver.quit()

# Check if headers were successfully captured
if req_headers:
    print("Request headers captured successfully.")
else:
    print("Failed to capture request headers.")
    exit(1)

try:
    print(req_headers, req_url)
    response = requests.get(req_url, headers=req_headers)
    print(f"API Response Status: {response.status_code}")
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("API call was successful!")
        print(response)
        print(response.json())  # Print the JSON response from the API
    else:
        print(f"API call failed with status code: {response.status_code}")
        print(response.text)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error during API call: {str(e)}")

If I open the same URL in normal browser I can see the call happening to this URL
https://hs-consumer-api.espncricinfo.com/v1/pages/match/scorecard?lang=en&seriesId=1444526&matchId=1444537
but not in the selenium-wire request.

What are the options that are available for me to solve this?
Why can I not see these requests happening in selenium-wire requests?


selenium-wire is officially no longer maintained; however, the last version of it can work well with blinker==1.7.0. Hope this helps.

are there any alternates that are available to selenium wire

Right now, I don't know but you can check dependencies version of selenium-wire you're using and install them correctly. Since pip cannot look after all the packages version.
